# Calling notifyDataSetChanged doesn't fire onContentChanged event of SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, events, cursor, adapter

I have this scenario

onResume of an activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (adapter1!=null) adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter2!=null) adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter3!=null) adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Adapter has been defined as:

```
public class ListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

   Cursor c;
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#onContentChanged()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onContentChanged() {
        // this is not called
        if (c!=null) c.requery();
        super.onContentChanged();
    }
}
```

And the onContentChanged event is not fired, although the onResume and the call to the adapter is issued.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [onContentChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#onContentChanged%28%29) method will be called when the ContentObserver on the cursor receives a change notification.

Comment: So in this case, what've I missed? How do I issue the requery?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any function which will directly requery the cursor. You can write a function in your adapter as requery which will requery the cursor and call notifyDataSetChanged from there.